# Print File from a Directory - Shell Script

Tags: shell

I have bunch of files in a did which I want to print using lp command from a crontab.

**example:**

```
/home/raj/orders$
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rajraj 151 2012-05-02 14:32 order_1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raj raj 151 2012-05-02 14:32 order_2.txt
```

I would like to print all these files like below

```
lp /home/raj/orders/order_1.txt
lp /home/raj/orders/order_1.txt
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? and if you have error messages, edit your posting to include those.

Answer (score 0):

This command may help you: `find $mydir -depth 1 | xargs lp`